# Org mode export dispatcher nil and key binding

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-export

I have two questions for exporting org file to PDF:

1. I would like not to open *Org Export Dispatcher* when my org file export to pdf through LaTeX. I checked [the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-Export-Dispatcher.html), then I found the following:

   > When the variable org-export-dispatch-use-expert-ui is set to a non-nil value, Org prompts in the minibuffer.

So, I set the following at my init.el. But it does not work. Are there any wrong for this setting?

```
(setq org-export-dispatch-use-expert-ui t)
```

2. To export a org file to a PDF file, I have to type `C-c C-e C-l C-O`. I don't like this key binding because of too much typing. Could you help me to set a concise keybinding?

Comment: Check the value with `C-h v org-export-dispatch-use-expert-ui RET`: is the value `t` as you expect? AFAICT, it works fine: I get the list of options in the minibuffer where I can choose `l o` to export to PDF. BTW, to get a PDF you have to type `C-c C-e l o`  - the last two are not control chars. And `C-c C-e l O` is for Beamer export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 2), you can go directly to the export function of interest and bind it to any key you want, e.g a function key, say F8:

```
(define-key org-mode-map [f8] (lambda () (interactive) (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf))))
```

Here we have to combine a couple of functions to do the export and then the open of the resulting PDF file. Note also that we have to label the function as `interactive` i.e. make it a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html#index-commands_002c-defining-1601). And finally, note that you lose the ability to select options (line `async`, `subtree` etc.) which the dispatcher allows you to use with an export: those are passed as optional arguments to `org-latex-export-to-pdf` by the dispatcher, but the above passes no arguments at all.